# Back up to and restore from a folder with date time stamp in its name

Tags: ms-release-management

I have an Agent-based Release Template. The Deployment Sequence includes three steps:

1. Make a back-up copy of the destination folder (using standard Copy
   File or Folder action)
2. Execute some custom component
3. In case of failure, restore content of the destination folder form backup

I want my backup folder name to include current date time stamp. How can I do that without writing a custom deployment script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't -- there is no timestamp token. You already hit upon the best approach, which is to write a PowerShell script to handle it.

Doing as much as you can with PowerShell is the preferred approach, as agent-based templates are Silverlighted. They are not doing any new development there, so you will want to start planning a migration to PowerShell-based "vNext" templates.